# CakePHP sanitize parameter

Tags: php, cakephp, sanitize

I have the following method in my CakePHP model:

```
public function login($login,$password){

    $arr = $this->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'deleted' => 0,
            'online' => 1,
            'login' => $login,
            'AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(password),'secretkey')=\''.$password.'\''
        )
    ));


    return $arr;
}
```

This method accepts two parameters ($login, $password) to authenticate the user.

I am wondering if this method is safe against SQL-Injection and other attacks.

If not, **which is the best way to sanitize the input parameters using CakePHP?**

I see that the Sanitize Class is deprecated as of 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Model::find()` is only safe when used properly!

You must know that only values in `key => value` pairs are being escaped, keys and non/numerically keyd values are inserted into the SQL query as is!

Quote from the docs

> **CakePHP only escapes the array values. You should never put user data into the keys. Doing so will make you vulnerable to SQL injections.**

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions**

So your `find()` call as is, is unsafe and prone to SQL injections, it should instead look like this:

```
$arr = $this->find('first',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'deleted' => 0,
        'online' => 1,
        'login' => $login,
        'AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(password),\'secretkey\')' => $password
    )
));
```

That way the user input `$login` and `$password` is being escaped properly.

Answer (score 0):

`$Model->find` should be safe, because it will escape the data before making the sql query.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#sql-escaping

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use the built-in CakePHP auth that will do the work for you (see doc : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

But if you need to do your own login function, Cakephp escape all parameter if you use built in methods like `save()` or `find()` ,... So, **YES**, your `find()` method **is safe**. (proven by the doc here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#sql-escaping)

For custom sql constructed by hand, you will have to escape manually your parameters because they aren't escaped by Cakephp